# Mobile menu css kinda working on ios

Tags: html, ios, css

I have a mobile menu that works as it should, but I do have one problem that I cant figure out!

On ios, when the menu dropdown expands vertically downwards, what goes below the actual physical screen, does not get any css, regarding hover, focus or active.

This is the html

```
            <ul class="mobile_menu">
                        <li><a href="#">A</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">B</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">C</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">D</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">E</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">F</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">G</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">H</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">I</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">J</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">K</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">L</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">M</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">N</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">O</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">P</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Q</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">R</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">S</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">T</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">U</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">V</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">W</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">X</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Z</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Y</a></li>
            </ul>
```

Yes its long...client wants it.

The css

```
.mobile_menu li a:hover {
  background-color: gray;
 }

.mobile_menu li a:focus {
  background-color: gray;
}

.mobile_menu li a:active {
  background-color: gray;
}
```

It works perfectly on any desktop and smartphone. But not on ios, if the dropdown menu is vertically longer than the actual screen.

Comment: add a max-height and a scroll

Comment: If we're not able to experience it, we're not able to help. Please provide a [mcve].

Comment: [Website](http://www.kvf.fo)